# How to create document preview with a list of images on it

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image

My program generate a list of images (the number of these images could change). 
I want to put these images objects in a preview page on my application, ready to be printed.

I already tried this way: [How to insert image object as picture in word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538601/how-to-insert-image-object-as-picture-in-word-document)
unfortunatly the suggested solution

```
Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Range(int1, int2)
Dim img As Image = qrGen.generateQRcodeImage("desiredInfoToEncloseInQRcode")
Clipboard.SetImage(img)
rng.Paste()
```

return me a compile error on third line:

```
it's not possibile to cast Image in Image
```

I don't need to use Word Document, so, if you could suggest me a better solution i'll be happy to listen you.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like here it is just having a hard time converting an image to a bitmap.  Convert img to a bitmap and then pass that to SetImage()

```
    Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Range(int1, int2)
    Dim img As Image = qrGen.generateQRcodeImage("desiredInfoToEncloseInQRcode")
    Dim bmpImage as new Drawing.Image(img)
    Clipboard.SetImage(bmpImage)
    rng.Paste()
```